# Normal Distribution Question Help

Tags: normal-distribution

A car manufacturer introduces a new method of assembling a particular component. A sample of assembly times (minutes) taken after the new method had become established was:

27, 19, 68, 41, 17, 52, 35, 72, 38

a) Calculate a 99% Confidence Interval for the mean assembly time:

mean = 41

standard deviation = 19.723

n = 9

degrees of freedom = 8

using inverse t-distribution:

multiplier = 3.355

99% Confidence Interval = 41 +- 3.355 x (19.723/3)

= (18.943, 63.057)

b) State any assumptions it was necessary to make in order to calculate the confidence interval in a

Sample is random and population is normally distributed.

c) A larger random sample of 45 assembly times had a mean of 36.3 minutes with a standard deviation of 9.8 minutes:

n = 45, mean = 36.3, sd = 9.8. 99% CI:

work out using invNormal: area = 0.99, s.d. = 1, mean = 0.

multiplier = 2.326

99% CI = 36.3 +- 2.326 +- (9.8/(root 45))

99% CI = (32.902, 39.698)

answers for a) and b) are correct but answer for c is incorrect (32.5-40.1). What have I done wrong?

Comment: You did not multiply but just added. Look at the formula for a CI interval

Comment: Btw: You are aware that you used the standard error. So you get a CI interval for the 'true' mean.

Comment: I meant 2.326 x (9.8/root 45)

Comment: What is the question? And what is the answer of the book?

Comment: I've wrote out the whole question and the answer in the book is stated at the end.

Comment: Because this is a two-sided interval, the Normal multiplier for an area of $0.99$ is not $2.326:$ it's $2.576.$  You did the calculation correctly for the t distribution but not for the Normal distribution, suggesting your software or tables might have an inconsistent interface.  You're not using Excel by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Your CI needs to be 2.5758... so using InvNormal:
Tail: central
Area: 0.99
SD: 1
Mean: 0
XInv= +- 2.5758...
You used the right/left tail which is why you got 2.326
Your answers should then be 32.537 (3dp) to 40.063 (3dp)